# Adding search option to above the column names

Tags: javascript, jquery, free-jqgrid

I have running JQGRID version 4.9.1, thanks to Oleg.
I am trying to add search functionality to the columns. I am trying to implement the search input fields on top of columns. When the user types something, it show only those values.

I am attaching an image hoping to clarify my question.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean the same behavior like `filterToolbar` do, but you want to hold searching elements above the column headers? Moreover I'd recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.13.0 - it's the current version of free jqGrid. It has compatibility to 4.9.1, it has better performance and more new features, which can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. i will upgrade to jqGrid 4.13.0. I think I solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution looking at the source code on the projects [gitHUB](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/free-jqgrid.github.io/blob/master/api-documentation/index.t).

It is activated by default I believe. In my case, I had it turned off in one of the settings.